# Using idle-vue with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I would like to use the `idle-vue` plug in with `Laravel` but I can't quite figure out how to register the module in my `app.js` file.

The `idle-vue` docs show this:

```
import IdleVue from "idle-vue";
import store from './store'

const eventsHub = new Vue();

Vue.use(IdleVue, {
  eventEmitter: eventsHub,
  store,
  idleTime: 3000, // 3 seconds
  startAtIdle: false
});
```

What is correct way to register this component in Laravel?

Answer (score -1):

You have to follow the same step as mentioned in `idle-vue` doc.

Your app.js would look like below.

```
import Vue from 'vue'

// Your code
import IdleVue from "idle-vue";
import store from './store'

const eventsHub = new Vue();

Vue.use(IdleVue, {
    eventEmitter: eventsHub,
    store,
    idleTime: 3000, // 3 seconds
    startAtIdle: false
});
// Your code ends

// Register vue instance using id in div tag.
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   // Added code from document
   data () {
       return {
           messageStr: 'Hello'
       }
   },
   onIdle() {
       this.messageStr = 'ZZZ'
   },
   onActive() {
       this.messageStr = 'Hello'
   }
});
```

[idle-vue document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idle-vue)

Blade file

```
<div id=app>
    <p>
        {{ messageStr }}
    </p>  
</div>
//Call compiled js file from your asset directory
<script src="{{ asset('app.js') }}"><script>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you just wrote. 1. The link you provided does not have what you wrote 2. I posted the same code above. 3. Clearly that is not the way you register it in Laravel which is precisely my problem